# T SQL Order By Specific Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In TSQL I'm querying a bunch of accounts based on certain criteria.  Each of these accounts have a main account or base account.  My business line only wants to send out mailings to the main or base account address and not to all the other subordinate account addresses.

I know how to do an order by DESC and ASC, but this is different based on whatever the main/base account is.

Any thoughts on how to do this in TSQL?

Comment: Can you show an example with expected input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with further research.  The main or base account will also have a regular account...Works like a charm

```
    Select Baseacctnbr, acctnbr,
BaseAcctOrder =
  Case
    When baseacctnbr = acctnbr then 1
    Else 0
  End
From MyTable
Order by BaseAcctOrder
```

[image]

I'm not posting the acct numbers for privacy, but the first 2 accounts are the main or base accounts and the last 2 accounts are regular accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement to assign numerical values to whatever you want and then sort by that.

```
SELECT email, account
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN account = 'base' THEN 1
        WHEN account = 'main' THEN 2
    END
```